# Easy way to view only uploaded songs?

Tags: google-play-music

Is there an easy way to view only songs that I've uploaded? I've uploaded a lot of songs and also gotten a lot of songs from the store when it was offering many songs for free. Sometimes I only want to listen to the songs from the store, which I can do by selecting "Free and purchased", but there's no obvious way to only list songs that I've uploaded. Is it possible to do without having to put them all in a playlist, and if so, how?